# TOpenDialog - zip as files

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-xe

How it is possible in open&save dialogs to force zip archives to be displayed as files, not as folders?

By displayed as folders I mean like this:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Windows file open dialog on Vista and higher supports an IFileDialogEvents interface.

One of the events (or callback if you will) is the `OnFolderChanging` event. It allows the implementer to stop navigation to a particular location. Using this event would enable you to stop entering a zip file as a folder, even when that capability is enabled by default in the Windows installation running your app. Don't see how it would enable navigation into a zip though if that is not enabled in Windows itself.

See: [IFileDialogEvents Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775876%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775876(v=VS.85).aspx ) for details.

The AlphaControls probably use this method. To do it yourself, you would "only" have to implement a handler for the TOpenDialog.OnFolderChange event (Thanks David).

To read more about using the [Common Item Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913(v=VS.85).aspx

Note: Pre-Vista common dialogs also support events, known as notifications in these versions. It does include a FolderChange notification, but no FolderChanging one that I can find. See [Common Dialog Box Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468811%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468811(v=VS.85).aspx for a list of supported notifications. And [Dialog Boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632588(v=VS.85).aspx) ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632588(v=VS.85).aspx ) for the "entry" point to dialog boxes.

Comment: @David: Ah, thanks, didn't have a chance yet to open Delphi :-) Edited my answer.